# How to download kernel soruce after updated kernel

Tags: kernel

Current kernel runing was v5.15.0-73, How I can download v5.15.0-73 kernel source. not k5.4.

My system informations:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
src $ uname -r
5.15.0-73-generic
```

Checking currently availabe kernel source .deb.

```
src $ dpkg -S /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-73-generic
linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-73-generic
tmp $ sudo apt-cache search linux-source
linux-source - Linux kernel source with Ubuntu patches
linux-source-5.4.0 - Linux kernel source for version 5.4.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-gkeop-source-5.4.0 - Linux kernel source for version 5.4.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-hwe-5.11-source-5.11.0 - Linux kernel source for version 5.11.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-hwe-5.13-source-5.13.0 - Linux kernel source for version 5.13.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-hwe-5.15-source-5.15.0 - Linux kernel source for version 5.15.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-hwe-5.8-source-5.8.0 - Linux kernel source for version 5.8.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-intel-5.13-source-5.13.0 - Linux kernel source for version 5.13.0 with Ubuntu patches
```

Comment: Your output shows `linux-hwe-5.15-source-5.15.0`, what's wrong with that?

Comment: I only get  *linux-hwe-5.15-source-5.15.0* by _apt-cacahe search_  , it seems no what I want, my currently is  5.15.0-73-generic, However, I download manually from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/amd64/linux-source-5.15.0/5.15.0-75.82 is working now, Just want to know what is the generic method via ***apt*** command

Comment: Have you checked the actual package version of `linux-hwe-5.15-source-5.15.0`?